# Cut out parts from videos

Tags: video, imovie, quicktime, video-editing

I know I can trim videos at the beginning or at the end with QuickTime Player — And practically any other video-editing-app.

But is there a simple way to cut out parts within a video — say ad-breaks in a tv-recording?

I mean, sure, it might be relatively simple to do with iMovie, but than I have to import and export — and that takes some time.

Isn't there a simple solution (probably without long re-encodings during import/export) to cut out parts out of mp4-videos?

Example:

```
|AD|---Movie---|AD|-------Movie-------|AD|---Movie---|AD|
```

I want to trim the video and cut out the ads, so only the «Movie»-parts remain (as one file).

```
|-------------Movie-------------|
```

Comment: Do you want to do this using a graphical tool and visually identify the parts to cut out? Alternatively, do you know the times and durations you want to cut out?

Comment: @GrahamMiln: Well, I'm speaking of hunderts of videos / tv-recordings. So it might be faster if i can visually identify the parts to cut out right in the tool where the cutting is happening, instead of have to first write out the times and durations and then add those numbers to another tool, i guess. So a graphical tool would be really great. but this should not be a deal breaker ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also trim from the middle with QuickTime player, not just from the end. Position the marker at the start of your edit, and do <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> (Split Clip), Then move the red line to the end of the region you want to remove and split it again there. You can now select the mid portion of the video (it should get a yellow border) and delete it.

See below for the view when you have done both splits, but not yet deleted...

[image: Screengrab]

Comment: FTW! wow that just blew my mind! :D … I always thought «split» will split it into 2 separate files — never tried it out though — :-D … perfect. thank for this, @beroe