# Is there a free tool that allows for cutting of videos?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, video

I am downloading AVI files from a German "online" video recording service. These files don't work with quicktime, but using the Elmedia video player (via app store) does the job.

Now I would like to "cut" those videos (basically selecting the *real* content of the videos, as they always contain additional 5 minutes before/after the actual recording).

I installed *avidemux* (using *brew cast install avidemux), and the tool installs. But when I open these AVI video files ... it seems that the buttons to select A/B boundaries for cutting are simply disabled. And on top of that, audio isn't in sync when avidemux is playing my AVIs - so I doubt that avidemux cutting the video would give me a correct file in the end.

As mentioned: quicktime refuses to play my avis,so this existing [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239651/cut-out-parts-from-videos) on how to trim using quicktime doesn't help me.

Thus: are there other tools for Mac Os that work better?

Comment: What you are looking for is "video trimming". [Free Video Cutter Joiner](https://www.anymp4.com/free-video-cutter-joiner/) seems to be a decent option and you can find more similar apps from the app store. That said, you could also use VLC player to convert the files to another format and use quicktime to trim. Also, [VLC player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is the go to player when you need to play any video format. I typically use [iSkysoft Video Converter](http://apple.co/2BVr0sx) for stuff like this, since I've bought it for video conversion purposes. It also has the trim feature.

Comment: @Joonas VLC is unfortunately a no-go in my environment.

Comment: If you're okay with command-line tools, you could try [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/). They have macOS builds.

Comment: I am using ffmpeg for conversions sometimes. I wasn't aware that you can use it for trimming as well. But I have to admit that I prefer a ui tool here. Instead of manually writing down time stamps to then pass them to the command line tooling.

Comment: @JAB ffmpeg works ... just some trouble with the end time ... in case you want to turn this into an answer, you will get my vote ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After checking the various solutions, I guess I will stick with

- Elmedia video player
- and ffmpeg

It is a bit cumbersome: as you first have to use the video player to find start/end timestamps for cutting. As soon as you got those numbers:

```
 ffmpeg -i IN.avi -ss 00:05:48.0 -to 01:35:10.0 -c copy OUT.avi
```

where -ss gives the start time stamp and -to the end point (and because *both* timestamps apply to the IN stream, no manual subtraction is required).

Using this command, it takes about 3 seconds to reduce a 1.2 GB file to 920 MB.

The big advantage: just two small tools require installation + super quick time for actual cutting.

Comment: The best part about this solution is most tools use the `ffmpeg` library anyway.  This is **exactly** the solution I was thinking of when I read the question.

Answer (score 6):

You could just put them into iMovie and trim the beginning and end and export them.

I tried using iMovie with .avi files before posting this answer, so I know it works.

Comment: Don't think it supports avi format.

Comment: It does; I tried it before posting this answer.

Comment: Huh... I seem to remember it didn't. In that case it may be the simplest answer...

Comment: Maybe Apple added AVI support recently.

Comment: AVI is just a container, it is also about the *exact* content of that container. Installing it right now ... will give feedback later on!

Comment: Sigh. After 30 minutes download for the 2 GB installer ... it tells me it cant *import* any of my avi files.

Comment: Is that for iMovie?

Comment: Yes. I would not complain on your answer if I wasn't talking about the solution you suggested :-)

Comment: Strange. What version of macOS are you running? And what version of iMovie are you running? I’m on version 10.1.8 of iMovie and macOS high sierra on a 2015 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

[Filmora Video Editor](https://www.iskysoft.us/lp/filmora-video-editor/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIuoLepvu21wIVS5PtCh273QBCEAAYASAAEgJRM_D_BwE) have a free trial and accept many input format like MP4, AVI, FLV, MKV, M4V, MOV, MPG, MPEG, VOB, DAT, TS, M2TS, WMV, ASF, DV, DIF, NUT, H264, NSV, PSP, 3GP, EVO, RM, TP, TRP, DVR-MS, etc.

[anymp4](http://anymp4.com/app-store/free-mp4-converter), have a free version with this features: convert MOV/MKV/AVI/WMV/FLV/VOB/SWF/M4V to MP4 and Adjust video effect, rotate, flip, add watermark, clip and merge, etc.anymp4.com/app-store/free-mp4-converter

Last but not least [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org), a free software that run via command line, you can trim or convert and save the video at the same quality

Comment: There is a *free* **trial** version of the tool. When you turn to the app store or the actual product page of that company ... as said: the free one is only for trial - and the pro one costs 60 USD or 55 Euros!

Comment: yes, I've see, so look at this anymp4, the free version have this features: convert MOV/MKV/AVI/WMV/FLV/VOB/SWF/M4V to MP4 and Adjust video effect, rotate, flip, add watermark, clip and merge, etc.https://www.anymp4.com/app-store/free-mp4-converter/

Comment: That sounds more helpful ;-)

Comment: @claudio Please add this to the answer, and update your answer to point out that the existing one is just a trial.

Comment: The problem I see: this tool allows trimming - but I couldn't find an option to **not** convert the input. But I absolutely dont want to convert. Conversion means that the complete file is read and a *new* output file is **computed**.

Comment: Hi GhostCat  mm... no payng, not reencoding... so ok :)  if you are confortable with terminal ffmpeg http://www.ffmpeg.org/ can help you and here https://superuser.com/questions/377343/cut-part-from-video-file-from-start-position-to-end-position-with-ffmpeg how you can use it

Answer (score 1):

I attempted using [Ghost Cat's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/308429/50585) but was receiving the following error:

```
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted
```

This is what ended up working for me:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -ss 00:05:42.0 -to 00:07:39.0 -c:v libx264 output.avi
```